# Accessing Backend HANA XSJS from SAP Conversational AI Chatbot - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error

Tags: sap-conversational-ai, xsjs

I created an XSJS Service in backend HANA Database through eclipse. When I call the service from POSTMAN, it works fine and gets me the result. But when I call the same service from SAP CAI chatbot, it gives an error : getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND.

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcnHa.jpg)

[SAP CAI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlXvJ.jpg)

Thanks and Regards
     Vivek

Answer (score 0):

are you inside a VPN network? SAP CAI is a public website and therefore can not request IPs internally of a private network.